# React app + heroku server not working on production, but working fine in dev

Tags: reactjs, heroku, server, production, vercel

I am working on `React` application which is querying from a `server`. I have deployed the server on `heroku`. When I am testing in `dev`, the `application` is behaving as expected. But when I am using it on `vercel` deployment, it is failing as `heroku` server is not responding properly.

Following is the server code of the query:

```
app.get(`/allPlans`, async (req, res) => {
    console.log("allPlans() query");
    ret = await Plans.find({});
    f = [];
    for (i = 0; i < ret.length; i++) {
      f.push(ret[i].name);
    }
    console.log(f);
    return res.status(200).send(f);
  });
```

Folowing is the code I am using to query from the client using `axios`:

```
const endPoint = "/allPlans";
let ret = await axios.get(endPoint);
console.log(ret.data);
```

In the `dev` environment, when I am deploying the application on `localhost:3000`, this is returning me a nice [`array`](https://cryptic-bayou-91116.herokuapp.com/allPlans).

```
["test","myPlan190","myPlan987"]
```

But in the actual production on vercel it is returning the following object(You can check this message in the console by going on the [vercel deployment](https://planner-pcrsehfg3-akcgjc007.vercel.app/dashboard)):
[image]

All suggestions are welcome.

[Github repo](https://github.com/akcgjc007/hackrush-2021/tree/6d05555da40feedf1de024d7f9cef24240f482a9)

[Vercel deployment](https://planner-pcrsehfg3-akcgjc007.vercel.app/dashboard)

[Server status](https://cryptic-bayou-91116.herokuapp.com/status)

[Heroku server query which is failing from axios, but working elsewise](https://cryptic-bayou-91116.herokuapp.com/allPlans)

Comment: It might be a simple case of listening on the correct port. Yours is set up on 5000 and heroku (I'm not 100% about this) is 8080. Remember to restart server and also it might be worth an npm run build.

Comment: Do you want to say that the `heroku` server is not working correctly?
Because [server status](https://planner-pcrsehfg3-akcgjc007.vercel.app/dashboard) is returing OK.

Comment: I can't see any request from your react app to your back-end on Heroku.

Comment: Check the above written `axios` code.

Comment: Yeah, I mean the network console. There is no request to your back-end on Heroku. Probably you trying to send a request to the URL of your front-end app.

Comment: Yes, @voxtool mentioned that. So I entered the complete `URL` in `axios` query, instead of proxying it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I checked you repository and also checked the XHR requests on your Vercel deployment and as far as I can see it making only one, which is:

> Request URL: https://planner-pcrsehfg3-akcgjc007.vercel.app/allPlans

It is not making an actual call to the server. I see that in Dashboard.js you are requiring axios from the package. I did not find any created instance of axios. So essentualy there is nothing to append in front of "/allPlans". Either create an axios instance with the right url "https://cryptic-bayou-91116.herokuapp.com" of just test it by putting the whole url "https://cryptic-bayou-91116.herokuapp.com/allPlans" inside the `axios` call in `Dashboard.js`.

Following is the updated code for an axios query:

```
const baseURL = "https://cryptic-bayou-91116.herokuapp.com"
...
const endPoint = baseURL + "/allPlans";
let ret = await axios.get(endPoint);
console.log(ret.data);
```

Comment: But, I am using the proxy to forward the requests like this:
`"proxy": "https://cryptic-bayou-91116.herokuapp.com",`

Comment: Thanks, this resolved my issue. Although I am convinced why it was not working previously. Anyways, marking this as a solution.

Comment: Well if you want to use axios the way you use it now, you need to create an new file something like instance.js and const axios = require("axios"); const instance = axios.create({baseURL:"https://cryptic-bayou-91116.herokuapp.com"}); export default instance;. And then when you use axios in Dashboard.js or anywhere else import the file you created - './instance' or etc. Not from the library, like you are doing now: const axios = require("axios");. You can read more about it here: https://medium.datadriveninvestor.com/axios-instance-interceptors-682868f0de2d

Answer (score 0):

fHeroku randomly changed application binding port.

You may set port by:

```
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000
```

for this use in you app [dotenv](https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv)

Or edit file  .env on heroku. Install [Heroku CLI](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli):

```
heroku login

heroku run bash -a app_name

touch .env

echo "PORT=3000" >> .env

check variable by

cat .env
```